# Measuring distances between distributions of ordinal variables

Tags: distributions, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, distance, distance-functions

I'd like to be able to measure how "different" two distributions of ordinal (but not interval) variables $X$ and $Y$ are. Given three random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$ I'd also like to be able to say whether $X$ is "more different" from $Y$ than $Z$ is from $Y$, etc.

Essentially, I'd like to find a distance function (in the mathematical sense) that strictly assumes ordinality (i.e. it does not reduce the variables to categorical ones, but it also does not assume arbitrary intervals between ranks).

The Mann-Whitney U test is a useful tool to determine whether two ordinal samples come from the same distribution. However, the U statistic itself is not a distance function as it trivially fails the requirements of reflexivity (U is not zero for identical samples) and symmetry (the values of U are different depending over which sample we sum the ranks).

Despite this, I can show that the simple transformation $\lvert \frac{n_1n_2}{2} - U \rvert$, where $n_1, n_2$ are sizes of the two samples *is in fact* a distance function satisfying reflexivity, symmetry and the triangle inequality. I would assume that because of its potential applications and close relationship to Mann-Whitney's U, it would be a fairly common approach to measure distances between ordinal distributions, but I cannot find any information on anything like it being used in the literature.

Does this metric have any specific name and is it used in practice? If not, then why, and what are some preferred alternatives?

Comment: The [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) will accommodate any distance function on the space of values of the ordinal variables.  (They don't even have to be ordinal.)  Have you considered that?

Comment: @whuber I can't say that I am fully groking all the details, but it seems to me that defining any sort of cost associated with "moving" points of the distribution to other values essentially defines a (different kind of) distance between the ranks, thus essentially making the variable an interval one (as the whole point of a strictly ordinal variable is that we have to be agnostic about the relative distances between the ranks).

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you are asking.  Any distance that respects the order of your data would legitimately serve as a basis for the "distance function" you seek.  It seems to me that any such distance function would be tantamount to some implicit assumption of varying relative distances among the values, so it looks like your objection might be unavoidable no matter what solution is offered.

Comment: It is not the case in the distance based on Mann-Whitney U that I am defining. To obtain the Mann-Whitney U statistic you can simply consider all pairs of points $(x, y)$ such that $x \in X, y \in Y$ and count the number of times $x$ outranks $y$. But the relative ranking does not matter, i.e. if the rank of $x$ is 1 it does not matter if the rank of $y$ is 2 or 100, it still counts the same.

Comment: Right -- but that actually is *overlooking* much of the information available in the ordinal structure of the values.  I'm still wondering what your constraints and assumptions truly are.

Comment: You are right that it is overlooking some of the available information. Essentially, for ordinal variables, i.e. ranks, we cannot say how does the difference between a pair of ranks i,j compare to the difference between some other pair or ranks k, l. Consider a Likert scale with the options "Somewhat likely", "Likely", "Very likely" (and equivalent options for "unlikely"). Not only do we not know what exactly each of those mean in quantitative terms, we also cannot know if the difference between "Very likely" and "Likely" is the same as the difference between "LIkely" and "Somewhat likely".

Comment: Re "cannot know:" perhaps not, but there are good ways of estimating those differences when you have other variables available for analysis.

Comment: Mann-Whitney measures/tests the difference in the gravity placement between the distributions, not any difference in distributions. Two symmetric distributions with the same median, one bell-shape, the other bimodal, are not different for M-W.